# MSAL Flask Authentication get ID Token

Tags: flask, oauth, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I'm exploring MSAL Flask Authentication example from Microsoft provided samples [here](https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-authentication/tree/3ae401d8ee0813fb71bf3b6cf6fc734ce2c62139). While running this, it returns a set of claims contained in the ID Token. What I want is to modify this code and see the actual ID Token that is returned by the Microsoft Identity Platform. Which code block should I use?

Comment: It's in the returned token result see [under the hood](https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-authentication/tree/3ae401d8ee0813fb71bf3b6cf6fc734ce2c62139#under-the-hood)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is use the Under the hood provided [example](https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-webapp) like @PGHE suggested to examine how it is working.

> This is just for R&D purpose to see how MSAL works in Python. Usually one don't interact directly with the OIDC\OAuth token(s). Instead the claims inside those tokens, at the end of the day, are required\important!

When you `pip3 install msal`, there is a file located at `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/identity/web.py`.
In the `complete_log_in` function of the `web.py`, you need to modify function so that the `id_token` and the `access_token` are extracted from the `result` dictionary like:

```
        cache = self._load_cache()
        if auth_response:  # Auth Code flow
            try:
                result = self._build_msal_app(
                    client_credential=self._client_credential,
                    cache=cache,
                    ).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
                        self._session.get(self._AUTH_FLOW, {}), auth_response)
                idToken = result["id_token"]
                accToken = result["access_token"]
```

This way, you can get the OIDC\OAuth ID Token or Access token(s).